# Deleted users still leave some trace behind

Tags: bug, deleted-accounts

I am not sure whether this is a bug, but shouldn't the system message generated when a user deletes his/her post also be normalised if the user requests deletion?

Case in point (viewable for 10K and diamonds on Math.SE): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/44378/1543

The user/OP's account was deleted, as one can see from the greyed-out normalised username attached to the post. But the system message indicating deletion still shows the user's original username.

**Edit**: Screenshot:

[image]

Ignore the "edited by" line, some other user edited the post before it was deleted. But look at the bottom left where it says "deleted by C" (I left the first letter to show that it is not "user9413"; it is also not one of the diamond mods); the displayed name there is/was the username of the now deleted user9413.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot so the rest of us can see? Block out any names if necessary

Comment: @ChrisF: if I block out names, wouldn't it just look like a normal deleted post? :) But I'll post one anyway.

Comment: Well the actual name is really irrelevant :) Just highlight where the name should have been anonymised.

Comment: You can sometime also deduce the username of a deleted account from the @tags in the comments, and *that* situation can persist in the open (i.e. on un-deleted posts).

Comment: @dmckee: yes. But that we have to live with, I think, unless we gain the ability to automatically change @-tags when the target changes user names.

Comment: @lunboks: why, it is indeed! I'll add my vote to close as dupe.

Comment: Because usernames are not unique it is felt that any attempt to automatically manipulate @tags is bound to be hopelessly buggy. All suggests to do anything like that are [status-declined].